# How to sort a 2d array based on one row in java

Tags: java, sorting

How to sort a 2d array using Arrays.sort in java 
For example Array I have

```
1 2 3 4; 
8 2 4 9
```

Sorted array should be like

```
2 3 1 4; 
2 4 8 9
```

Sorting can be done on the basis of any row.
I searched google and stack overflow but all of them were giving answers for the sorting on the basis of any one column.
I tried writing comparator function but failed.
My requirement is that I wanted to use both the binarySearch function as well  as the sort function of arrays.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Looks like you've managed to sort the array by hand.  Bravo.  Now, you need to write some code to replicate what you've done by hand.  Once you've tried, you can post a [mcve] of your attempt, and ask for help.  But until you've shown effort trying to solve the problem, we won't spend any effort trying to guess where you've gone wrong.

Comment: How does this generalize to multi-row matrices?  Is it always the second row that ends up sorted? The last? The row with the greatest sum?  Something else?  Or are the matrices always 2 rows by 4 columns?  Please read "[ask]" and then [edit] your question to explain exactly what rules your sorting operation must obey, including valid inputs, examples of inputs and outputs, and exactly how your implementation (which you haven't posted) isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

As per you example columns are linked i.e. `1, 8` , `2, 2`, `3, 4` and `4, 9`, so it is better to create an object for linked data. Putting them in object will ensure that they stay together. check will example for sort based on any column.

```
public class ArrayColumnSortExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rowSize = 2;
        ArrayRow[] arr = new ArrayRow[4];

        arr[0] = new ArrayRow(rowSize);
        arr[1] = new ArrayRow(rowSize);
        arr[2] = new ArrayRow(rowSize);
        arr[3] = new ArrayRow(rowSize);

        arr[0].row[0] = 1;
        arr[0].row[1] = 8;
        arr[1].row[0] = 2;
        arr[1].row[1] = 2;
        arr[2].row[0] = 3;
        arr[2].row[1] = 4;
        arr[3].row[0] = 4;
        arr[3].row[1] = 9;

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<rowSize; j++)
                System.out.print(arr[i].row[j]+" ");
            System.out.println();
        }

        ArrayRow.sortColumn = 0; //change value based on sorting requirement
        Arrays.sort(arr);

        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<rowSize; j++)
                System.out.print(arr[i].row[j]+" ");
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    static class ArrayRow implements Comparable<ArrayRow>{
        Integer[] row;
        static int sortColumn;
        public ArrayRow(int size) {
            this.row = new Integer[size];
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(ArrayRow o) {
            return this.row[sortColumn].compareTo(o.row[sortColumn]);
        }       
    }

}
```

Apply some optimization based on your requirement.